# CakePHP3 mapping RESTFul routes

Tags: rest, api, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to config a RESTful API resources mapping in CakePHP3. I followed some tuts but can't make it works.

- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-restful-routes
- http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-prefix-route-a-cakephp-3-rest-api/

I'm using 'prefix' route to map `/api/v2/:resource` with my sub-folders inside Controllers folder.

My file structure:

[image]

And this is my routing config

```
Router::prefix('api/v2', function ($routes) {

    $routes->resources('Users');

    // $routes->get('users', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view']);
    // $routes->post('users', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'create']);
    // $routes->post('token', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'token']);

    // $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

As I read in the tuts i mention before, this should works, but i get a Missing Contoller Exception for ApiController.

If I uncomment the last line, enabling `fallbacks` it works fine, but it's not matching the Controller Methods with the HTTP method GET, POST, DELETE, PUT as [CakePHP3 documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-restful-routes) mention.

Any ideas? My Cake version in `3.5.8`
Thanks!!

**EDIT:** using `bin/cake routes` it's seems like the routes are fine. I'm using Postman to make request with differents HTTP methods to test this.

[image]

**EDIT 2:** I tried with another prefix `Foo` to avoid the V2 case sensitive issue, and well, this is extrage, the routes seems to be fine, but cake are not matching any of them..
[image]
[image]

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP - thanks!

Comment: That being said, for starters the foldername is wrong, it should be `V2` (capital `V`) and the namespace for your controller should match accordingly, this is important on case sensitive filesystems. The current error however suggests that the route isn't being matched, which indicates that the problem might be with your request - please add according information on how exactly you are requesting which URL exactly.

Comment: @ndm The "Missing Controller" error is expected since his folder name is incorrect.

Comment: @ADmad Correct, but I would expect the error to be about missing the `UsersController` in that case, not the `ApiController`.

Comment: @ndm You are right. I do get missing `UsersController` error and not missing `ApiController` when naming the folder `v2` instead of `V2`.

That said with correct folder names the example code he has shown works just fine. So probably he has other problems too.

Comment: @mauriblint FYI you can use `bin/cake routes` to see all routes mapped for your app.

Comment: Excellent, I edit the question to add the output of this command, it's looks fine! Also i tryed with the folder as V2 and v2, and it's the same.

Comment: @ndm Yes, since the error was missing Controller, it's mean that the prefix routing is not working, because Cake is looking for the Controller and not for the subfolders..

Comment: @ADmad I tried with both, V2/v2  and it's the same. As I said before, if i remove the comment from the $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute') the routes are matching fine, but not with the HTTP method as we want in a RESTful API

Comment: Again, please elaborate on what _exactly_ your request looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Your folder name should be `V2` not `v2`.

Comment: Good luck renaming that on Windows if you're using Git. First rename `v2` to `_v2`, and then `_v2` to `V2`. Otherwise Git won't see the case change. Windows has burned me many times on case changes.

Comment: @ADmad check my last edit in the question, I add another example to discard de V2 folder name issue